# Fastest way to enumerate Sql Servers

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm aware of how to enumerate sql servers using the SqlDataSourceEnumerator and also how to do it using SMO objects.  Both of these ways are slow.  Are these pretty much the only options or are there any other ways to do it that might be a little faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Cache the results from one of those running in a background process and query the cache?

Comment: Since Management Studio and Visual Studio are equally slow, I'd say that's pretty much the only way :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never noticed a significant speed difference or discovered a way to make either one faster.

However, if you are distributing your applications to end users or running it on server machines, then I would suggest using SqlDataSourceEnumerator so that you don't have to hassle with SMO being registered on the machines or version compatibility with SMO.

In addition, if you are presenting the list to users to select from, you could improve the user experience by providing the values in an editable combobox where they could enter the name of the server if they know it and as soon as you have finished collecting the list of available servers, you could populate the dropdown.

I haven't looked at the SMO objects in awhile, but if they support events that report back as servers are discovered, this could improve the performance even more since you could add items to the dropdown as they are reported by SMO. However, it is just speculation on my part at this point that this behavior would be supported.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using SMO for other things already so that's not really an issue, but SMO objects don't support those kind of events that I'm aware of.  However, the way I've dealt with it was to combine what you said about having an editable combobox with an asynchronous method that populates the combobox.  That way if they know what they want they can type it in, or they can wait for it to appear in the dropdown.  I think it's slightly better than the SSMS dialog b/c it doesn't force you to wait for the servers to load if you hit the dropdown and it's not ready yet.